# Provide file download links in iJulia notebook results

Tags: julia, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

I'd like to produce a data file that is downloaded by the user, either automatically or through a hyperlink.

For instance, is there an equivalent of [this iPython approach](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb#Links-to-local-files) for iJulia?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to auto-generate a link in Jupyter Notebook, such that people can download? If so, I do this in Vega.jl (so people can download PNG files of graphs) with the following:

```
              window.setTimeout(function() {
                var pnglink = document.getElementById(\"$divid\").getElementsByTagName(\"canvas\")[0].toDataURL(\"image/png\")
                document.getElementById(\"$divid\").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br><a href=\"' + pnglink + '\" download>Save as PNG</a>')
              }, 20);
```

https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/Vega.jl/blob/master/src/render.jl#L65-L69

Basically, this code finds the div that the output is in (which is known at the time of Julia code running, before the output is rendered), then auto-generates an HTML link with the base64 representation of the PNG. Depending on your content, this obviously may differ (since the `.toDataURL` method has to have your file type in the method).

Answer (score 2):

I translated from original [`FileLink`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/lib/display.py#L300) definition to julia:

```
type FileLink
    file_path::ByteString
end
type FileLinks
    links::Vector{FileLink}
end
FileLinks(paths::Vector{ByteString}) = FileLinks(map(FileLink,paths))

function Base.writemime(st::IO, ty::MIME"text/html", fl::FileLink)
    write(st, "<a href=$(fl.file_path) target='_blank'>$(fl.file_path)</a>")
end

function Base.writemime(st::IO, ty::MIME"text/html", file_links::FileLinks)
    for fl in file_links.links
        Base.writemime(st, ty, fl)
        write(st,"<br>")
    end
end

FileLinks(readdir("."))
```

Works on locally hosted IJulia/IPython/Jupyter server, but you may have problems with remote servers (eg Sage).

Answer (score 1):

Using NBViewer to serve Jupyter notebooks statically works also with IJulia.

- http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/Ismael-VC/3d54a43d73f3a3fbd922

As shown in it's home page:

[image]

In this example I give NBViewer the link of one of my IJulia notebooks that is hosted in Gist, notice that GitHub/Gist now also renders Jupyter noteboks:

- https://gist.github.com/Ismael-VC/3d54a43d73f3a3fbd922